Using an environment variable to ensure that paths with certain names are never searched in find?
Is there an environment variable I can set to be read by find (WSL Ubuntu 20.XX LTS) so that it never searches paths that contain, for instance node_module or .git when find runs a search?
Or would this be an alias or something I would have to specify every time I use the find command using -path and -prune ?

I doubt there will be such a thing, but in the unlikely case where there is, it would be for a specific find implementation, so please edit and tell us what OS you are using.

@terdon WSL Ubuntu 20.XX LTS.

@terdon Are there any similar alternative tools that maybe have the ability to specify an environment variable for this purpose?

Not that I know of.

@terdon If I wanted to suggest this; where would be a good place to do so?
(or does nobody use find anymore?)

I can just use sed to do it, but it's still annoying.

You could presumably suggest it on the coreutils mailing list (coreutils@gnu.org) but I really doubt it would be implemented as it doesn't sound like something a lot of people would need. You normally search and just exclude what you want to exclude.

@terdon It's a waste to have to type it over and over everytime when you can just specify it globally in .bashrc.

It is yes, but that's your use case. I have never wanted or needed anything like this, I really don't think many people regularly want to exclude specific directories. And, if you do, since the tool already has functionalities like -prune, it isn't hard to set up a local alias or function or script that does it. On the other hand, having env vars affect tool behavior in such a way would be quite surprising to those not aware of it.

You might want to try https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

No implementation of find that I know has such an environment variable, but find generally makes use of shared libraries, linked at runtime by the dynamic linker.
find will typically read the contents of directories using the standard readdir() function in the C library, and the dynamic linker does query the $LD_PRELOAD environment variable (on GNU systems at least) for a list of other shared objects to load through which you can override functions from those linked libraries.
If you create a hide-git.c file with:
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dirp)
{
  static struct dirent* (*orig) (DIR*);
  struct dirent *entp;

  if (!orig) {
    orig = (struct dirent* (*) (DIR*)) dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "readdir");
    if (!orig) abort();
  }
  do {
    entp = (*orig)(dirp);
  } while (entp && strcmp(entp->d_name, ".git") == 0);
  return entp;
}

as content, and compile it as:
cc -Wall -fPIC -shared -o hide-git.so hide-git.c -ldl

And then do:
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/that/hide-git.so

Then the .git entry (any file called .git whether they're of type directory or not) will be hidden from the result of readdir() and anything that uses it to get the contents of directories.
Note that as $LD_PRELOAD is taken into account at execution time at the very beginning, for that to take effect for shell globs, you'd have to re-execute your shell in that environment.
Example:
$ mkdir -p {.git,.foo,bar}/{1..3}
$ ls -FA
bar/  .foo/  .git/
$ find .
.
./.git
./.git/1
./.git/2
./.git/3
./.foo
./.foo/1
./.foo/2
./.foo/3
./bar
./bar/1
./bar/2
./bar/3

$ export LD_PRELOAD=~/hide-git.so
$ ls -FA
bar/  .foo/
$ find .
.
./.foo
./.foo/1
./.foo/2
./.foo/3
./bar
./bar/1
./bar/2
./bar/3
$ echo .*
.foo .git
$ exec "$SHELL"
$ echo .*
.foo

Replace strcmp with strcasecmp if you want the match to be case insensitve¹, see also fnmatch() to do some shell-like pattern matching.
For the $LD_PRELOAD to apply only to some commands, instead of using export, you can run your commands as:
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/hide-git.so find ...

But beware that if you use -exec cmd in that find command, cmd will inherit that LD_PRELOAD. You could change that to -exec env -u LD_PRELOAD cmd or add a unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD") in the C code above (under the if (!orig) condition) to avoid that hijacking of readdir() to propagate across further executions².

Without using those tricks, you can always do:
find . '(' -name .git -prune ')' -o '(' ... ')' -print

In place of:
find . ...

(Remove -print if ... has any action predicate and beware -depth / -delete cannot be used).
Replace -name .git with -iname .git (where supported) or -name '.[gG][ıiIİ][tT] (where not) for case-insensitive matching.

If using zsh recursive glob instead of find, hidden files (those whose name starts with a .) are skipped by default.
When including them like by setting the globdot/dotglob option or using the D qualifier, you can keep skipping .git and its contents in recursive globs by replacing **/ (short for extendedglob (*/)# for any amount of sub-directories) with (^.git/)# (^ for negation and # for 0-or-more need extendedglob).
$ echo **/*
bar bar/1 bar/2 bar/3
$ echo **/*(D)
bar bar/1 bar/2 bar/3 .foo .foo/1 .foo/2 .foo/3 .git .git/1 .git/2 .git/3
$ set -o extendedglob
$ echo (^.git/)#*(D)
bar bar/1 bar/2 bar/3 .foo .foo/1 .foo/2 .foo/3 .git
$ echo (^.git/)#^.git(D)
bar bar/1 bar/2 bar/3 .foo .foo/1 .foo/2 .foo/3

Or you can filter-out those .git after the fact using the ~ except / and-not operator:
$ notgit='~(*/|).git(/*|)'
$ echo **/*$~notgit(D)
bar bar/1 bar/2 bar/3 .foo .foo/1 .foo/2 .foo/3

(and $~var for the contents of $var to be taken as a pattern and not literally).

As another alternative to find, see also fd (sometimes called fdfind to disambiguate with unrelated commands also called fd), which supports a configurable list of directories and files to ignore (will also look into .gitignore files and more).

¹ In locales where uppercase i is İ instead of I, whether that will match on .GİT instead of .GIT when the application has done a setlocale(LC_ALL, "") may vary with the system.
² Assuming the application otherwise uses the libc's environ/putenv()/setenv()... to maintain its environment and the exec*() functions that pass that environ to commands when executing them.

The manual page for my find implementation (find (GNU findutils) 4.10.0) contains a section near the end called "ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES" which lists the following:
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
       LANG   Provides a default value  for  the  internationalization
              variables that are unset or null.

       LC_ALL If  set to a non-empty string value, override the values
              of all the other internationalization variables.

       LC_COLLATE
              The POSIX standard specifies that this variable  affects
              the  pattern  matching  to be used for the -name option.
              GNU find uses the fnmatch(3) library  function,  and  so
              support  for  LC_COLLATE  depends on the system library.
              This variable also affects the interpretation of the re‐
              sponse to -ok; while the  LC_MESSAGES  variable  selects
              the  actual  pattern  used  to interpret the response to
              -ok, the interpretation of any  bracket  expressions  in
              the pattern will be affected by LC_COLLATE.

       LC_CTYPE
              This variable affects the treatment of character classes
              used  in  regular  expressions  and  also with the -name
              test, if the system's fnmatch(3) library  function  sup‐
              ports  this.  This variable also affects the interpreta‐
              tion of any character classes in the regular expressions
              used to interpret the response to the prompt  issued  by
              -ok.  The LC_CTYPE environment variable will also affect
              which  characters  are considered to be unprintable when
              filenames are printed; see  the  section  UNUSUAL  FILE‐
              NAMES.

       LC_MESSAGES
              Determines  the  locale to be used for internationalised
              messages.  If the POSIXLY_CORRECT  environment  variable
              is  set,  this also determines the interpretation of the
              response to the prompt made by the -ok action.

       NLSPATH
              Determines the location of the internationalisation mes‐
              sage catalogues.

       PATH   Affects the directories which are searched to  find  the
              executables invoked by -exec, -execdir, -ok and -okdir.

       POSIXLY_CORRECT
              Determines  the  block  size  used  by -ls and -fls.  If
              POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, blocks are units of  512  bytes.
              Otherwise they are units of 1024 bytes.

              Setting  this  variable  also turns off warning messages
              (that is, implies -nowarn) by default, because POSIX re‐
              quires that apart from the output for -ok, all  messages
              printed  on  stderr are diagnostics and must result in a
              non-zero exit status.

              When POSIXLY_CORRECT is not set, -perm +zzz  is  treated
              just  like  -perm  /zzz  if +zzz is not a valid symbolic
              mode.  When POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, such constructs  are
              treated as an error.

              When  POSIXLY_CORRECT is set, the response to the prompt
              made by the -ok action is interpreted according  to  the
              system's  message  catalogue, as opposed to according to
              find's own message translations.

       TZ     Affects the time zone used for some of the  time-related
              format directives of -printf and -fprintf.


Presumably, if it had any other variables, those would have been listed there so this version at least doesn't have what you are asking for and you would indeed need to set up an alias using -prune or just filtering the results after running.
